# Highcharts font styling via css

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to change the style of the labels on the x-axis and y-axis via CSS?

As far as I can see from the documentation, right now it's possible only using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can use only JS. However you can set `useHTML` to true, and then in formatter return HTML tags with classes. Then in CSS set styles for that classes.

There is only one limitation: HTML tags won't be exported.